# GOST support. OpenSSL, xmlsec

Tags: c++, openssl, xmlsec, gost3410

Im writing xml signing utility using C++ to run on Linux (only). And I need support of GOST, GOST2012.
I'm using xmlSecOpenSSLKeyDataGost2001Id, xmlSecOpenSSLKeyDataGostR3410_2012_256Id, xmlSecOpenSSLKeyDataGostR3410_2012_512Id in xmlSecKeyDataCreate() function.
Code compiles fine. But during link I'm getting error about undefined references to xmlSecOpenSSLKeyDataGost2001GetKlass,
xmlSecOpenSSLKeyDataGostR3410_2012_256GetKlass, xmlSecOpenSSLKeyDataGostR3410_2012_512GetKlass.

Should I add some specific library to add support of these methods?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it.
All you need to do is to build xmlsec library with --enable-gost and --enable-gost2012 flags. Then you need to configure your project to use newly built libraries (or install them).